# Adding a name of column with * in that

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch a data from the db with and rename as Area(wid*hght) how do I do this guys in SQL,

`SELECT conact(width,'*',height) as AREA(wid*hght)` .. but this gives me error in `AREA(wid*hght)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  an alias for column name you should use backtics around these string when are present special char

```
SELECT concat(width,'*',height) as `AREA(wid*hght)`
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT conact(width,'*',height) as "AREA(wid*hght)"
```